# How does one enable MySQL's strict sql mode using Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

When I enabled strict SQL mode on my development box, I found a bunch of SQL errors in my code. However, for the most part, I like using the production SQL box instead of my box, because there's realistic data on that machine to play with, and there's no overhead of keeping my local DB in sync with that DB.

However, there are a bunch of apps depending on that box which don't do... the best in terms of SQL. I'd like to enable strict mode for my application on an application specific basis using Zend_Db, and more specifically Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(); //Or how ever you store your DBs...
$db->getConnection()->query('SET sql_mode="TRADITIONAL"');
```

seemed to do the trick.